# Cardinality Proving Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

[Hi everyone, I am not sure of how to apply question 2, and Proposition 9.2.4(2) [which means Any subset A of a countable set B is countable] shown in 1 of the pictures above to solve questions 3(a) and (b)..

For 3(a) I believe I need to apply the fact that |A x C| = |B x D| as part of my proof... but how do I even do that? The even bewildering/confusing part is how do I even apply 3(a) and Proposition 9.2.4(2) shown above in one of the pictures for 3(b)?

Will appreciate it a lot if anyone can help me out with this. Thanks a lot!]

Image Links of the question and proposition:
Question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxtmg.jpg
Proposition: https://i.stack.imgur.com/89P2M.jpg

Comment: Do not vandalize your question when a user has answered your question. You even accepted the answer.  To render your question a non-question is vandalism on this site, particularly after another user took time to answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by showing that $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable. This can be done by finding an injective function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ and another injective function from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, and then applying the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem to show that there exists a bijection $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Then, since $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$, from Question 2 we can conclude that $A\times B$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, so it is countable.

Finally, for question 3(b), let $A_0$ and $B_0$ be countable sets. Let $A$ and $B$ be countably infinite sets such that $A_0\subseteq A$ and $B_0\subseteq B$. From question 2, we know that $A\times B$ is countable and since $A_0\times B_0 \subseteq A\times B$, Proposition 9.2.4(2) allows us to conclude that $A_0\times B_0$ is countable.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Does that mean for 3b I can just simply state as such as per what you have wrote without proving anything much, and that I also have to consider the case when one of them (either A or B) is countably infinite but the other is countably finite? For 3a, is it fine to define a function f: N --> A and function g: N--> B, and from there show how N x N is countable?

Comment: It's not necessary to consider multiple cases, because given a countable set X, there's always a countably infinite set C that contains X.  For 3a, I'd suggest starting by showing that NxN is countable by using the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem, as I stated above, because then all you need to do is use the result from question 2 to conclude that AxB is countable (because a set is countably infinite if and only if it has the same cardinality as N).

Comment: I see I see, so all I have to do is basically come up with 2 injective functions and thereafter quote the cantor bernstein theorem to conclude there is a bijection?

Comment: Exactly. Consider the function that maps each ordered pair of natural numbers (a,b) to 2^(a-1)*(2b-1) and show that it's an injection from NxN to N. Then, use the fact that the function that maps each natural number n to (n,n) is injective.

Comment: I see, just quoting canton bernstein theorem is sufficient? That means I don't have to justify why there is a bijection right?

Comment: Yes. Given two sets A and B, the theorem states that if there is an injection from A to B and an injection from B to A, then there is a bijection between A and B.

Comment: So if i treat the function f: NxN --> N as (a,b) to 2^(a-1)*(2b-1) then the reverse function g:N --> NxN will just be mapping from 2^(a-1)*(2b-1) to (a,b)?

Comment: It's not necessary to consider the inverse function of f (and you would have to show that it's surjective and injective for it to exist). It suffices to show that f is injective. Hint: use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: I see I see, that means I can use another random function of my choice to prove N---> NxN is injective? Thank you so much for replying swiftly to my questions!

Comment: Exactly, f(n)=(n,n) and g(n)=(n,0) are some easy examples of such functions. I'm glad that some of my replies have been useful!